# Change header text and keep the same design built in \fancyhead

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I'm trying to make a good looking header for even and odd pages and it works perfectly fine. But I would like for one section to change the text in the header (a name different than section or chapter), and keep the same design built with \fancyhead[]{}.

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\fill[red] ([xshift=1.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,1cm);%
\fill[black] (current page.north west) rectangle (0cm,1cm);%
\node[anchor=west] at (0,1.5cm) {\bfseries \color{white}{\leftmark}};
\node[anchor=west] at ([yshift=-0.608cm]current page.north west) {\bfseries \color{white}{Page \thepage}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\fancyhead[RO]
{
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
\fill[black] (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,1cm);
\fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle (0cm,1cm);
\node[anchor=east] at (0,1.5cm) {\bfseries \color{white}{\rightmark}};
\node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-0.608cm]current page.north east) {\bfseries \color{white}{Page \thepage}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}    
\lipsum[1-15]
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 2}    
\lipsum[1-15]
\lhead{Here is where I want another header, but still keep the layout}
\newpage   
\end{document}
```

If I use \lhead{The text}, the whole tikz design disappears and I end up having plain text in the header. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

Use `\markright{The text}`, which will set the `\rightmark` just like `\section` would do.

Be more careful with protecting end-of-lines: inside a `tikzpicture` they're ignored, outside it they're kept.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[red] ([xshift=1.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,1cm);
    \fill[black] (current page.north west) rectangle (0cm,1cm);
    \node[anchor=west] at (0,1.5cm) {\bfseries \color{white}{\leftmark}};
    \node[anchor=west] at ([yshift=-0.608cm]current page.north west) 
      {\bfseries \color{white}{Page \thepage}};
   \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancyhead[RO]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \fill[black] (current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,1cm);
    \fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle (0cm,1cm);
    \node[anchor=east] at (0,1.5cm) {\bfseries \color{white}{\rightmark}};
    \node[anchor=east] at ([yshift=-0.608cm]current page.north east)
      {\bfseries \color{white}{Page \thepage}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}    
\lipsum[1-15]
\newpage    
\section{Test Section 2}    
\lipsum[1-15]
\markright{The text}
\newpage   
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As the text in your headers comes from `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` you might get a solution by defining your own mark on that page. Like

```
\markboth{LEFT TEXT}{RIGHT TEXT}
```

But that depends on the presence of `\section` commands whether it will work. If the page boundaries are clearly defined, like with the `\newpage` in your example, it may help to put this code both at the beginning and the end of the page.

Another way is to replace `\leftmark` and `\rightmark` in your definitions with `\myleftmark` and `\myrightmark`, and define these as:

```
\newcommand{\myleftmark}{\leftmark}
\newcommand{\myrightmark}{\rightmark}
```

and the on that special page redefine these with

```
\renewcommand{\myleftmark}{SPECIAL TEXT}
\renewcommand{\myrightmark}{SPECIAL TEXT}
```

and define them back to the first ones after that page (or put that special page inside a TeX group).